# Is it possible to find data from MySQL by month using JPA and java.time.LocalDate date format?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I creating an application, for that I need to find data by month using `JPA` and `java.time.LocalDate`. So, is it possible to retrieve data by month from `mysql`?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You just need to make it query between days of a month. That's the same as "by month".

Comment: What is the data type of your column in MySql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find start and end date of month and use between method of JPA to find data of current month.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(System.currentTimeMillis() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ).withDayOfMonth(1);

LocalDate end = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(System.currentTimeMillis() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ).plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);
```

In Repository

```
List<Object> findByCreatedateGreaterThanAndCreatedateLessThan(LocalDate start,LocalDate end);
```

Comment: Why `ofEpochDay`? Seems like a strange approach.

Answer (score 5):

Its better to use the `between` keyword, it makes things allot shorter.

```
List<Object> findByCreatedateBetween(LocalDate start,LocalDate end);
```

Also if you want to use the `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` objects with Spring Data you should use the converter class `Jsr310JpaConverters` or else the documents will be stored as Blobs instead of Dates (which is bad for portability of the database). Please see this tutorial on how to implement the Converter.

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-java-8-date-and-time-jsr310/

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Get current month for particular time zone.
         .atDayOfMonth( 1 )                       // Get the first date of that month.
         .plusMonths( 1 )                         // Get first of next month for Half-Open query.
```

## Details

Assuming your column in MySQL is of [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) type…

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

#### Time zone

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### `YearMonth`

The `YearMonth` class represents an entire month. Getting the current month requires a time zone as discussed above. Around the beginning/ending of the month, the current moment could be “next” month in Auckland New Zealand while still “previous” month in Kolkata India.

```
YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.now( z ) ;
```

Get the first date of the month.

```
LocalDate start = currentMonth.atDayOfMonth( 1 ) ;
```

### Half-Open

Generally best to use the Half-Open `[)` approach to defining a span of time, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So defining a month means starting with the first date of the month and running up to, but not including, the first date of the following month.

```
LocalDate stop = start.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

### Query

Do *not* use the `BETWEEN` command in SQL as it is fully closed `[]`, both beginning and ending being inclusive. Half-Open uses `>= & <` logic.

```
SELECT when FROM tbl
WHERE when >= start 
AND when < stop 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's also useful

```
@Query("from PogWorkTime p  where p.codePto = :codePto and month(p.dateApply) = :month and year(p.dateApply) = :year")
Iterable<PtoExceptWorkTime> findByCodePtoAndDateApply_MonthAndDateApply_Year(@Param("codePto") String codePto,@Param("month") int month, @Param("year") int year);
```